# Show Image in Menu on ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, .net, toolbar

I want to show an image in a menu in an ArcMap AddIn toolbar. Here is my code in the  config.esriaddinx:

```xml
<Menus>
       <Menu id="GridViewMenu" caption="Grid View" image="Images\GridView.png">
          <Items>
            <Button refID="Button1" />
            <Button refID="Button2" />
            <Button refID="Button3" />
            <Button refID="Button4" separator="true"/>
            <Button refID="Button5" />
            <Button refID="Button6" />
          </Items>
        </Menu>
</Menus>
```

[image: Menu]

Why does it not show an image in menu?

Comment: What happens when you take out *caption="Grid View"* and leave *image="Images\GridView.png"* as the only option? You are certain that Images\GridView.png exists (and is readable by ArcMap... I think the biggest you can go is 32x32 but try it at 16x16)

Comment: I have used both 16*16 and 32*32 ; but same result. Image does not show. One thing, "the attribute "image" is not declared" is shown in case of Menu when I add image attribute. And when I take out caption attribute, it still does not show any image.

Comment: I can't see anything on it.. perhaps try isRootMenu="true". Unless the png is a format that the system doesn't like or can't read, try convert to .bmp with Paint or IView, being the most basic form it might work.

Comment: No, it does not work .. :( ..

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Menu_Element/001v000000z8000000/) `image` is not an attribute of a menu element. In fact I cannot think of any menu on the ArcMap interface that behaves in this manner, i.e. has an image instead of a word, despite being able to change it to an image via the customize mode.

So it's not a property you can define in the config file. Now I may be wrong, others can correct me but you would probably override it's display using the [ICommandItem](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002300000071000000) Interface, may be some code placed in the New() or OnUpdate() method?

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find that help file when I went looking. I've not implemented menu before but was vaguely remembering that Image wasn't an attribute but couldn't find a reference. I do have some old code that implements ICommandBar / ICommandItem (creating a toolbar the *old* way)... no guarantee that would work either.